# How to construct a bijection between all base 2 representation of real numbers and all possible permutation of a binary string

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove |$\mathbb{R}$|  = |P($\mathbb{N}$)|. I want to use base 2 numbers to do this.

I have show that there exist a bijection between base 10 and base 2. However, I cannot think of a good bijectiive, or even injective, function between the sets base 2 and the set of all permutations of the infinite binary string.

Comment: The proof is straightforward using Cantor Bernstein, but I suspec giving an explicit map would be more difficult.

Comment: I read $P()$ as powerset, but you speak of pemutations. Could you clarify?

Comment: P(A) is the power set

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Permutation is the number of possible way to order a binary string of length n, in this case that string is infinite $2^{n}$ for the set